# Error on simple ansible play-book

Tags: ansible

I'm running a simple ansible playbook and getting an error:

> *ERROR: parse error: playbooks must be formatted as a YAML list, got type 'str'*

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
   - name: Get server availability by pinging it
     ping:

   - name: Get server hostname
     command: hostname
```

Not sure where the problem is. Ansible v1.9.6

Comment: File seems ok. Show your `ansible-playbook` command line.

Comment: nothing fancy: 
ansible-playbook hostname.yml inventory

Comment: Tried `ansible-playbook -i inventory hostname.yml`?

Comment: **-i** of course. I need to get some rest :)

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov can you post an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from comment: missing `-i` flag in `ansible-playbook hostname.yml inventory`.